# Adding condition to findAll and findAllBy methods

Tags: grails-orm, grails-3.0

In my domain class User I would like to have boolean flag active. Is there any way to override methods like `User.findAll` and `User.findAllBy`... by adding condition `active == true`?

What I want to achieve is calling `User.findAll` means find all users where active is true, and calling dynamic method like `User.findAllByName('mike')` will return all users with name mike and active flag set to true.

My grails version is **3.0.3**

Comment: You might want to look into the Grails hibernate plugin. Here's a helpful blog [link](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/grails-hibernate-filter-plugin-a-life-saver/) that addresses a similar need.

Comment: Grails hibernate plugin is not working with grails 3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've migrated original [hibernate-filter](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) plugin to be able to use it with new Grails 3. New version is published at official [Grails 3 plugins repository](https://bintray.com/grails/plugins) with grails-hibernate-filter name, direct link to plugin [here](https://bintray.com/piotrchowaniec/grails-plugins/grails-hibernate-filter/view)